# CakePHP - strange behavior with $this->Auth->login() - CakePHP 2.2.1

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I've created on a local machine (XAMPP) app with login and it works great.

Now, when I deploy it on a server, $this->Auth->login() returns false.

I've `debug($this->request->data)` and it's the same as local.

I've tested QUERY on sql_dump on phpmyadmin and it's perfect (it found a user) but it's still not logged in. (No user on `$this->Auth->user();`).

What do you think the problem can be?

I've tried changing `session.cookie_path` and still nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Security.salt in your /Config/core.php is the same on the production and development server. It has probably something todo with the Session.

Try to change the CakePHP session storage(Session.defaults) to cake instead of php.

Comment: Perfect. It helped me in a situation where I had two apps with identical core, but different security salts. It appears that value of 'php' confused Auth component a lot. Changed it to 'cake' and all went ok. Thanks.